# Segmentation fault after using dynamic bitset in C++

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a variable length linear feedback shift register, so I used dynamic bitset instead from boost library instead of bitset. After compiling the program, and when running it, it produced Segmentation fault directly after it shows the contents of xorArray. I think the mistake is in the definition of the dynamic bitset variables, but I can't figure it out. There are three variables, inpSeq, operSeq and bit. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>  //Standard library.
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>    //Library for 10 handling.
#include <vector>    //Variable size array.
#include <algorithm> //We use sorting from it.

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int y = 0;
 int turnCount = 0;
 int count1 = 0, count0 = 0;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq;
 int polyLoc;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit;
 vector <int> xorArray;
 vector <int> keyReg;
 cout << "Enter a bit sequence: \n";
 cin >> inpSeq;
 int seq_end = inpSeq.size() - 1;
 cout << "Enter polynomial:";
 cin >> polyLoc;
 while(polyLoc>0)
 {
  xorArray.push_back(polyLoc%10);
  polyLoc/=10;
 }
 cout << "xorArray is: ";
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < xorArray.size(); i++)
 {
  cout << xorArray[i] << " ";
 }
 sort(xorArray.rbegin(), xorArray.rend());
 cout << "\n";
 operSeq = inpSeq;
 keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
  int x = xorArray[0];
  cout << "x is: " << x << "\n";
  for ( unsigned int  i = 0; i < xorArray.size();  i++)
  {
   cout << xorArray[i] << "\n";
  }
  cout << "bit 3 of initial " << bit[seq_end] << "\n";
  do {
  for (unsigned int r = 1; r < xorArray.size(); r++)
  {
  bit[seq_end] = operSeq[x];
  cout << "bit 3 from prev: " << bit[seq_end] << "\n";
  y = xorArray[r];
//  cout << "opseq[y] is: " << operSeq[y] << "\n";
  bit[seq_end] = bit[seq_end] ^ operSeq[y];
//  cout << "bit[3] after xor: " << bit[seq_end] << "\n";
  }
  operSeq >>= 1;
//  cout <<"operSeq after shift: " <<  operSeq << "\n";
  operSeq[seq_end]  = bit[seq_end];
//  cout <<"opserSeq bit 4 after = bit[3]: " << operSeq[seq_end] << "\n";
//  cout <<"new operSeq: " << operSeq << "\n";
  keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
  turnCount ++;
  cout << "--\n";
 }
 while ((operSeq != inpSeq) && (turnCount < 20));
 cout << "Generated key is: ";
 for (unsigned int k = 0; k < keyReg.size(); k++)
  {
  cout  <<  keyReg[k];
  }
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Bit 1 positions: ";
 for ( unsigned int g = 0; g < xorArray.size(); g++)
 {
  cout << xorArray[g];
 }
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Key length is: " << keyReg.size();
 cout << "\n";
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < keyReg.size(); i++)
 {
  if (keyReg[i]==1)
   {
    count1++;
   }
  else {
    count0++;
  }
 }
 cout << "Number of 0's: " << count0 << "\n";
 cout << "Number of 1's: " << count1 << "\n";
 if ( keyReg.size()%2 ==0)
  {
   cout << "key length is even. \n";
   if (count1==count0)
    {
   cout << "Key is perfect! \n";
    }
  else {
   cout << "Key is not perfect! \n";
    }
 }
  else
   {
  cout << "key length is odd. \n";
   if  ((count1==count0+1) || (count0==count1+1))
    {
   cout << "Key is perfect! \n";
    }
  else {
   cout << "Key is not perfect! \n";
    }
   }
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what a "variable length linear feedback shift register" is.  Perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: A linear feedback shift register takes a sequence of bits, know as the initial card, say for example 1010, it XORs the bits specified by a polynomial, say x^4+x^3+x^0, in this case it will xor the first and last bits and but the result in the last bit after shifting the sequence one bit to the right. My code ignores the x^4 here, the code was working fine when I was using bitset, the sequence was fixed to 4 bits length only. But I want it to be variable.

Comment: "Fault directly after entering the polynomial" - obviously not, as the next half dozen lines are ok.  Delete the lines of crap at the end until you've got just enough to see fault, then we can focus our effort to help you.  -1 for poor effort and consideration.

Comment: Done! Strong language...

Comment: @MohamedAhmed We know what an LFSR is. It was the *variable length* part that raised brows.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I thought it might be so, that you know what an LFSR is, but have I made myself clear on the _variable length_ part?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed I think so. Not entirely convinced of the usefulness, but at least I understand what you're trying to do. No worries.

Comment: @WhozCraig I want to enable the end user to enter a bit sequence of the length that he or she desires, instead of being constrained by a fixed size sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that you didn't size the dynamic_bitsets before you used it.  You should call [`dynamic_bitset::resize`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: I find the documentation of dynamic bitset to be a little complicated, and in fact, I am a beginner at C++ programming and programming as a whole. May you please provide an example for the edit I need to make to my source code?

Comment: Look at the "constructor" section.  You were constructing a dynamic_bitset using the default constructor.  If you read the docs, default constructing a dynamic_bitset creates a bitset with size 0.

Comment: What is the purpose of "bool value = false"?

Comment: I managed to get some knowledge of C++ by reading http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html I think I should head for their forum to look for answers for this type of questions. I think it is not accepted hereto ask questions requesting to know the correct syntax of some code you want to use, isn't is so?

Comment: In the documentation I linked to, did you see this:  `dynamic_bitset(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`.  That is the constructor that is called when you declared your dynamic_bitset's in your program.  This is the default constructor (can take 0 arguments).  If you read on, you see it mentioning that the bitset size is 0.

Comment: Yes, I already saw it, I want it to be of variable size, taking the length of the sequence that the usere enters you mentioned resize(), so do I use it like `resize(size_type num_bits, bool value = false);` what to but in the place of num_bits? And what is the purpose of bool value = false?

Comment: How many bits are you going to have?  If it's n, then it's resize(n).  I think it should be straightforward -- you don't know how many bits you start with, ok.  But then when you do know the number of bits, you resize the bitset accordingly.  Don't know how to explain it any simpler than that.  The `false` is the value of the bits that have been "added" (if the resize will make the bitset larger than the previous size).

Comment: One final minor question, if I want to resize inpSeq to be of size x, shall I use `inpSeq.resize(x);`?

Comment: Yes.  I would suggest trying things out first and then coming back if there are any further questions.