# dynamic bitset initialized and called from other method gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-dynamic-bitset

I initialize a dynamic bitset in a constructor of a class and then call a method of that class to fill it with some values. I get a segmentation fault no matter which part of the bitset I try to access.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{ 
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy(200000); // all 0's by default
  std::cout << occupancy.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << occupancy[1234] << "\n";
  fill_occupancy();
}

void MyClass::fill_occupancy()
{
  std::cout << occupancy[1234] << "\n";
}
```

The constructor prints out the correct output of 200000 and 0, but when enters the fill_occupancy methood it gives segfault.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970640/segmentation-fault-after-using-dynamic-bitset-in-c), but I don't think that applies, bc I construct the bitset properly as I see the correct output from the constructor.

I've found a way to make it work if I simply make the method fill_occupancy() to accept argument of type dynamic_bitset<> and then call it with fill_occupancy(occupancy). Why this works and the code above does not? Other data types I can call in other methods without having them as argument.

Thank you.

**Edit**
This is in case someone would be interested in more detailed explanation:

```
class MyClass()
{ 
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy; //calls default bitset constructor (i.e size 0)
}
```

In the MyClass constructor, calling just

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{ 
  occupancy(200000); // this is WRONG
}
```

produces error as the occupancy is set to zero size. To resize it one has to call

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{ 
  occupancy.resize(200000); // this is CORRECT
}
```

Then occupancy has the correct size and is member of MyClass and as such can be accessed from any other method of the class such as `fill_occupancy()`.

My original construction made the occupancy a local variable of the same name as the member one so in the constructor it worked but everywhere else the member (of size 0) was called which explains the segfault.

Thank again juanchopanza for explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is instantiating a *local* bitset called `occupancy`, not a data member of the same name:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy(200000); // local variable
```

It seems like you want to initialize a data member, which you can do like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(): occupancy(200000)
{ 
  std::cout << occupancy.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << occupancy[1234] << "\n";
  fill_occupancy();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to set the occupancy size in the constructor itself based on some other parameters? That is actually the reason why I used dynamic bitset and not a std::bitset.

Comment: @jano Then do that. But your code doesn't show what you want to do, so it is difficult to answer precisely.

Comment: Ok I've learnt a lesson: What I can do is to use the construction juanchopanza stated above and if needed I can call `occupancy.resize(some_other_int)` to get the size I want.

Comment: As far as I understand the reason why my original form works for other variable types such as int, is because in MyClass declaration dynamic_bitset calls a default constructor so the bitset is set to size 0, then in the MyClass constructor the  $boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy(200000);$ is interpreted as a local variable with the same name. However for e.g. int variable I don't have to set a size so changing its value in the class constructor simply works on the data member. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the code does not show that and I'm sorry I haven't realized that might be a problem. You answered correctly the question that was stated and it helped me to find out an answer to question I wanted to ask :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jano Your analysis is not quite right. If the variable were an `int`, and you did not initialize it in the constructor, and you made the same mistake of declaring a local int with the same name, reading from the int data member elsewhere in your class would be undefined behaviour, because the int needs to be explicitly initialized. That is a feature of C and C++ built-in types.

Comment: Yes I agree, I've realized that when editing the question. See now the edited version if you agree with the more detailed explanation.

Comment: @jano Almost right. You have fallen foul of another piece of C++ weirdness: this is actually a function declaration: `boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy();`. Replace it by `boost::dynamic_bitset<> occupancy;`.

Comment: You're right! I made a mistake when copying it from my source. Thanks for pointing it out. I fixed this now in the edited version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, "occupancy" is a locale Variable, so you should not access it in the outside.

Comment: not quite; if you set A=5 in the constructor of the class, provided you declared it in the class.h file then you can access A in all of the class methods.

Comment: @jano Then it wouldn't be a local variable. `occupancy` *is* a local variable in your code. There is 0 ambiguity about that.